# Unable to install lync 2013 sdk with VS 2013

Tags: lync-server-2010

I am using VS 2013 and need to reference the Lync 2013 SDK. The install fails with:

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1 or higher not found

Is there any work around or do I have to downgrade to VS 2012?

Thanks,
Bill

Answer (score 9):

I got it solved.

You can fix it by installing WinRAR and then right-clicking the .EXE file (the installer), extract it, and then run the 64 bit setup file. It installs to `Program Files` from where you can just reference the DLLs.

Comment: At my computer the .dll files are located at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\LyncSDK\Assemblie though I do not know if those came with the Installation of Office 2013...