# The type or namespace name 'Lync' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'

Tags: c#, lync

I'm trying to write

```
using Microsoft.Lync.Model;
```

Does anyone know how to add reference `Microsoft.Lync`? Do I need to install `Microsoft Lync Basic` or is there any other way to solve the problem?

Comment: Maybe you need this SDK? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36824

Comment: I tried to install it, but I got an error:
Microsoft Lync 2013 not found. Go here to download and install: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=248583

Comment: and does going there to install work?

Comment: I haven't installed Microsoft Lync Basic yet, because I hope there is another way to fix it

Comment: Are you really planning to try and write software that works against Lync without having it locally installed at all? Do you not think that will make e.g. debugging extremely difficult?

Comment: Yes, you're right. So, do you think I have to install Microsoft Lync Basic 2013?

Answer (score 1):

For those who may follow.  I had this problem today and discovered the solution here:
[Unable to install lync 2013 sdk with VS 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693968/unable-to-install-lync-2013-sdk-with-vs-2013)

"You can fix it by installing WinRAR and then right-clicking the .EXE file (the installer), extract it, and then run the 64 bit setup file."